# Angular UI Grid: Multiple Grids with same Column Defs

Tags: javascript, angular, angular-ui-grid

So currently in my application there are multiple grids on load of each routes . For example ,on load of **/home** displays one grid with some data (coming from backend api call) and columnDefs (columns for grid), whereas on load of **/employee** has one grid with some data (coming from backend api call) and respective columnDefs. For both these routes i have separate controllers and respective columnDefs attached on $scope.gridOptions inside controllers.Well this setup works fine but i need to achieve modularity on making a generic ui-grid-service for all columns in application and not necessarily for a single route or single grid.

To ellaborate better ,since *columnDefs* (columns for grids) are almost same for all the grids in my application on all probable routes, I wish to write one service which has all the columnDefs and then hide/show what is desired in each route and in each controller respectively.

Can anyone please help on this ? It will be extremely helpful if you can let know as to how to proceed with the same ?

Comment: Hi ! It would be better if you checkout [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) of your code for future endeavor at Stack overflow. -Thank you

Comment: Can anyone reply to this ? I will be glad . Thanks for the utmost help